# Displaying an HTML file from Winform

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I'm just creating a simple calculator in C# (Windows Form).

I've created a "User Help" which is an HTML file, what I want is to display that HTML file if the user clicks on the "Help" button in the WinForm.

How to open the HTML file on button click in WinForm?

I don't plan to provide this PDF file on hard disk of user, which means that I have to embed this HTML into the calculator (WinForm) and have to display it on the button click.

Comment: Why not to be nice to user and open HTML in regular browser with `Process.Start`?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to put your Html pages on Winforms is to load it on webBrowser Control by this lines:

```
var uri = new Uri(filepath); 
webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
```

or load your html texts to webbrowsers html by this

```
FileStream source = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = source;
```

or

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `WebBrowser` control.

Check: [How to: Add Web Browser Capabilities to a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s8ys666%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you to using Visual Studio, you can do.
1)Add control `WebBrowser` in the winform
2)Add file html on resource in the project, click right button to do
3)Then write

```
string html = Properties.Resources.Details;
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

I hope useful this is